# Looking for a fitting function

Tags: statistics, curves, regression-analysis

I want to fit some data points that follow this trend:

[image]

I've tried an exponential of this kind: $f(x)= a\exp(-bx)$ but it's not good enough. Could you give me any hint?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe explore $ae^{-bx^2}$?

Comment: Brilliant, it works. Thanks very much!